# Webflux security authorisation test with bearer token (JWT) and custom claim

Tags: testing, jwt, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot (2.3.6.RELEASE) service that is acting as a resource server, it has been implemented using Webflux, client jwts are provided by a third party identity server.
I am attempting to test the security of the endpoints using JUnit 5 and `@SpringBootTest`. (For the record security appears to work as required during manual testing)

I am mutating the WebTestClient to include a JWT with an appropriate claim (`myClaim`), however in my custom `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` there is no bearer token in the requests header, thus with nothing to decode or claim to validate the request fails authorisation, as it should.
My test setup is thus:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void willAllowAccessForJwtWithValidClaim() {
        webTestClient.mutateWith(mockJwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.claim("myClaim", "{myValue}")))
                .get()
                .uri("/securedEndpoint")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                    .isOk();
    }
}
```

I have been attempting to follow this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/test-webflux.html#testing-bearer-authentication-2)
I have tried the client with and without `.filter(basicAuthentication())` just in case :)

It appears to me that the `mockJwt()` isint being put into the requests `Authorization` header field.

I also think that the `ReactiveJwtDecoder` being injected into my `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` will attempt to decode the test JWT against the identity provider which will fail.

I could mock the `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` or the `ReativeJwtDecoder`.

Is there anything I am missing?
Perhaps there is a way to create "test" JWTs using the Identity Services JWK set uri?

Additional detail:
Details of the `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` and Security Config

```
public class MyReactiveAuthorizationManager implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext> {
    private static final AuthorizationDecision UNAUTHORISED = new AuthorizationDecision(false);

    private final ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public JwtRoleReactiveAuthorizationManager(final ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(final Mono<Authentication> authentication, final AuthorizationContext context) {
        final ServerWebExchange exchange = context.getExchange();
        if (null == exchange) {
            return Mono.just(UNAUTHORISED);
        }

        final List<String> authorisationHeaders = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getOrEmpty(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authorisationHeaders.isEmpty()) {
            return Mono.just(UNAUTHORISED);
        }

        final String bearer = authorisationHeaders.get(0);

        return jwtDecoder.decode(bearer.replace("Bearer ", ""))
                .flatMap(jwt -> determineAuthorisation(jwt.getClaimAsStringList("myClaim")));
    }

    private Mono<AuthorizationDecision> determineAuthorisation(final List<String> claimValues) {
        if (Objects.isNull(claimValues)) {
            return Mono.just(UNAUTHORISED);
        } else {
            return Mono.just(new AuthorizationDecision(!Collections.disjoint(claimValues, List.of("myValues")));
        }
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(final ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                            final ReactiveAuthorizationManager reactiveAuthorizationManager) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/securedEndpoint").access(reactiveAuthorizationManager)
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `.bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext)` is used when you have a mocked `ApplicationContext` you on the otherhand seem to be running a full server `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
` which means you should be using `bindToServer()` instead https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html

Comment: or you omit the `bindTo...` and it will be configured per default https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you for the comments :)  Interestingly if I attempt a bindToServer I cant `apply(springSecurity()` its the wrong type, but worth playing around here a bit more deeply.  If I Autowire the `WebTestClient` I get a `NullPointerException`.  I suspect a bug, or the functionality isint there yet as I havent seen any documentation on handling custom claims.

Comment: well usually when you get a token, you map the token using a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` to map the claims which is fully documented https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you that is very helpful.  It is difficult to know the correct approach when there are so many different solution out there.  I will look at `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` as well as `JwtAuthenticationConverter` which may be more appropriate to my use case.

Comment: Just curious that why you don't put your token in the test client header?

Comment: @WUJ My main motivation for not doing so; was that I would have to create a token, which is always a pain in my opinion, but is more so in this case as the signing secret etc are only available by a call to the "identity servers" "JWK set" endpoint.  I was also trying to not have the test require external infrastructure to be in place.  I am not at the point where I have it mostly working, but `@MockBean`/mocking doesnt appear to be working, spring giveth and spring taketh :)

Comment: Understood, what I'm thinking here is that, you may create a token generator class to create Token, for example: JWTClaimsSet.Builder then Sign it with JWSSigner. This way you can have a customized token. Then on your test client-side, just do client.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, bearer ......)

Comment: @WUJ Interesting thought. I am not aware of JWSSigner.  I think I have this sorted now (famous last words), but I will certainly checkout JWSSigner it may prove useful in the future, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, it turns out that what I am actually doing is using a custom claim as an "Authority", that is saying "myClaim" must contain a value of "x" to allow access to a given path.
This is a little different to the claim being a simple custom claim, i.e. an additional bit of data (a users preferred colour scheme perhaps) in the token.
With that in mind I realised that the behaviour I was observing under testing was probably correct, so instead of implementing a `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` I choose to configure a `ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter`:

```
    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter converter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        converter.setAuthorityPrefix("");       // 1
        converter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("myClaim");

        final Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> rxConverter = new ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(converter);

        final ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(rxConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
```

(Comment 1;  The `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` prepends "SCOPE_" to the claim value, this can be controlled using `setAuthorityPrefix` [see](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction))

This required a tweak to the `SecurityWebFilterChain` configuration:

```
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("securedEndpoint").hasAnyAuthority("myValue)
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter));
```

**Tests**

```
@SpringBootTest
class ControllerTest {
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Autowired
    public void setUp(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext) // 2
                .apply(springSecurity())  // 3
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        webTestClient
                .mutateWith(mockJwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("myValue")))  // 4
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("/securedEndpoint")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                    .isOk()
    } 
}
```

To make the tests "work it appears that the `WebTestClient` needs to bind to the application context (at comment 2).
Ideally I would have prefered to have the `WebTestClient` bind to the server, however the `apply(springSecurity())` (at comment 3) doesnt return an appropriate type for `apply` when using `bindToServer`

There are a number of different ways to "mock" the JWT when testing, the one used (at comment 4) for alternatives see the spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-testing-jwt)

I hope this helps somebody else in the future, security and OAuth2 can be confusing :)

Thanks go @Toerktumlare for pointing me in the direction of useful documentation.