# Mocking JWT token in @SpringBootTest with WebTestClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I have the following controller class in a Spring Boot project:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> getUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
    try {
        final UserResponse userData = userService.getUser(userDetails.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userData);
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("User with id {} not found", userDetails.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

This resource is only accessible if the client sends a JWT token with `Authorization: Bearer <token>`. The `CustomUserDetails` are provided by a `CustomUserDetailsService` after having parsed the JWT token via a `JwtRequestFilter`.

Now I'd like to write a `@SpringBootTest` which uses a real HTTP client calling this resource. My first idea was to use a `MockMvc` object but then I read about the `WebTestClient` provided by Spring.

However I don't yet understand how I would be able to mock the JWT token. This is my initial attempt:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class UserControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void someTest() {
        final User user = createUser("foo@bar.com", "my-password");

        when(userRepo.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

        webTestClient
                .mutateWith(mockJwt())
                .get()
                .uri("/user")
                .header(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();
    }
```

This test fails with the following exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'webHandler' available`

However I'm not sure if my approach makes sense. Is `WebTestClient` the "correct" way? Or do I need to use a `WebClient`?

My security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public SecurityConfiguration(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors().and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .mvcMatcher("/services/**").authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(PUBLIC_RESOURCES).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Saw from another question of yours that you still have some issues. Please have a look at the code in this article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/ BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebTestClient` is the recommended replacement for `TestRestTemplate`.

A deep-dive into the Spring Security source at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security, shows some examples of use of `WebTestClient` with JWT. E.g.: `ServerOAuth2ResourceServerApplicationITests`

Given that you have a service `JwtTokenProvider` that is responsible for generating JWT-tokens, a test may look like below. Or, if possible, you may use constant tokens like in `ServerOAuth2ResourceServerApplicationITests`.

```
package no.yourcompany.yourapp.yourpackage;

import no.yourcompany.yourapp.configuration.JwtTokenProvider;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class YourIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Test
    public void postTest_withValidToken_receiveOk() {

        var tokenString = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("test-user", "P4ssword"));

        webTestClient
                .post().uri("/test")
                .headers(http -> http.setBearerAuth(tokenString))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

For `WebTestClient`, add this to POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a step into the right direction. However, the test now fails with `ClassNotFoundException`: `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter`

Comment: @RobertStrauch: Please see my updated answer and make sure you have the specified dependency. BR

Comment: @RobertStrauch: Added links to my answer in case you experience NPE.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm experiencing an NPE which seems to come from `mockJwt()`. I'll have a look...

Comment: @RobertStrauch: According to this accepted answer, maybe parts of your code from question is closer to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593952/webflux-security-authorisation-test-with-bearer-token-jwt-and-custom-claim/65628053#65628053

Comment: I guess that the referenced solution only works if the application actually uses a Webflux implementation. I don't think that mine does. I updated my question with my security config.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for 'non webflux' implementation? I got the same problem as you: No bean named 'webHandler' available